# UBound Array Definition

Tags: vba

Having trouble understanding how to use UBound.

If I have a dynamic column A where the rows count is constantly changing, but I want to grab the upper bound to define in a for loop - how would I go about doing so? I keep getting a runtime error with the below method.

```
arr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
For i = 1 to UBound(arr, 1)

etc. 

Next i
```

Comment: I get no error with the code you have provided.

Comment: What is the runtime error? If you were asked this question, wouldn't you want to know that?

Comment: The only time I get a run time error is if the region starting at A1 is empty or only has one value. In that case `arr` is not an array but a single variant value.

Comment: Apologies - was running and typing that. Runtime error was error 13, type mismatch. The sheet at hand does have a value in A1, which is a string (a header for the whole column)

Comment: Changed to a variant and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting an array equal to a range value, it automatically sets it as a two dimensional array, even if the range is only one column. Look at the example below:

```
 Private Sub workingWithArrayBounds()

    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim RowIndex As Long
    Dim ColumnIndex As Long

    Arr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

    'VBA FUNCTION FOR CHECKING IF SOMETHING IS AN ARRAY
    If IsArray(Arr) Then

        'FIRST LOOP GOES THROUGH THE ROWS
        For RowIndex = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1)

            'THE SECOND LOOP GOES THROUGH THE COLUMNS
            For ColumnIndex = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2)

                'NOW YOU HAVE ACCESS TO EACH ELEMENT USING THE ROWINDEX AND THE COLUMN INDEX
                Debug.Print Arr(RowIndex, ColumnIndex)

            Next

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

If there is only one column of data, the bounds would look something like (1 to x, 1 to 1). So you would need to pass in the second bounds to it. To be safe, it is always recommended to use both the `LBound` and `UBound` when looping through arrays as these can vary from array to array.

Another thing to check is if the array is actually allocated. In the scenario of setting an array equal to the value of a range, you can first check if there are values actually in your range to retrieve.

An alternative is to use a function to check and see if array is empty or not. Cpearson has a good function for that as well as many other helpful functions @ http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm

```
Public Function IsArrayEmpty(Arr As Variant) As Boolean
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' IsArrayEmpty
' This function tests whether the array is empty (unallocated). Returns TRUE or FALSE.
'
' The VBA IsArray function indicates whether a variable is an array, but it does not
' distinguish between allocated and unallocated arrays. It will return TRUE for both
' allocated and unallocated arrays. This function tests whether the array has actually
' been allocated.
'
' This function is really the reverse of IsArrayAllocated.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim LB As Long
Dim UB As Long

Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next
If IsArray(Arr) = False Then
    ' we weren't passed an array, return True
    IsArrayEmpty = True
End If

' Attempt to get the UBound of the array. If the array is
' unallocated, an error will occur.
UB = UBound(Arr, 1)
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    IsArrayEmpty = True
Else
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' On rare occassion, under circumstances I
    ' cannot reliably replictate, Err.Number
    ' will be 0 for an unallocated, empty array.
    ' On these occassions, LBound is 0 and
    ' UBoung is -1.
    ' To accomodate the weird behavior, test to
    ' see if LB > UB. If so, the array is not
    ' allocated.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Err.Clear
    LB = LBound(Arr)
    If LB > UB Then
        IsArrayEmpty = True
    Else
        IsArrayEmpty = False
    End If
End If

End Function
```